# Map int to bool in NHibernate using a second table as data source

Tags: .net, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, mapping, has-one

I'm trying to do a map which I don't know if is supported in NHibernate.

I have a table A for which I have a mapping in Fluent NHibernate. 
I have another table called B in which I have to search for A.Id . If I find this Id in this table than I have to set a bool property in the mapping for class A to true, otherwise to false.

Between table A and table B there is a one to one relationship represented in the mapping with a HasOne method. 
The trouble is that HasOne don't have a CustomType method that I can use to convert the result to a bool property.

I would also be fine with casting the value to a bit or int from the mapping but I don't know how to do that.

Does anyone know if this is possible and if yes how can be done ?

Thank you, Mosu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Formula is made for such a scenario

```
Map(x => x.BooleanProperty).Formula("SELECT true IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM B WHERE B.A_id = Id)");
```

Edit:

another approach (not tested)

```
// public AMap()
Join("TableB", join =>
{
    join.KeyColumn("A_id");
    join.Optional();
    Map(x => x.BooleanPropery, "someBcolumn").Not.Insert().Not.Update().CustomType<NullToFalseElseTrue>();
});

// class A
public virtual bool BooleanPropery { get; private set; }
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm trying to avoid using SQL in the source code. Is there another solution to this ? I'm know trying to use a protected member and use its value in a method that will return a bool value.

Comment: In the second approach I can't get the column in the select and so i can't convert it in the CustomType (I get A.Id but I also need B.Id). I'm using your syntax. Do you have any idea what I'm doing wrong ?

Comment: cant you give b.id as the column for booleanproperty?

Comment: I gave the b.id column to booleanproperty but I don't get the b.id column in the result set. Not sure why. I will further investigate this tomorrow morning. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Firo offered the correct answer. 
However there is small issue with its code so I'm also answering to my question for a little more visibility (than as a comment).

```
Join("TableB", join =>
{
    join.KeyColumn("A_id");
    join.Optional();
    join.Map(x => x.BooleanPropery, "someBcolumn").Not.Insert().Not.Update().CustomType<NullToFalseElseTrue>();
});
```

The difference is small but important. 
Without the missing 'join' on the third line of the Join delegate you are saying to NHibernate that you are mapping the A_ID column with the BooleanProperty instead of B_Id as you would expect.